# Rewrite 301 page with parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I've looked the whole tutorials about htaccess and I can't find how to figure out my issue :

I want to redirect 301 this page :

```
welcome-user-32.htm
```

to

```
welcomeback-32.htm
```

the 32 is a user id that change from user to another accordingly...

I tried this but didnt success :

```
RewriteRule welcome-user-(.*)\.htm$ welcomeback-(.*)\.htm$ [L,R=301]
```

Thanks for taking the time to read my isse, I hope someone can help !

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (welcome\-user\-)(.*)\.htm  /welcomeback-$2.htm [R=301,L]
```

Comment: if you satisfied with this answer , don't forget to accept it